# What would happen if a wizard calls a familiar in the Ethereal Plane and then returns to the Material Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, planes, ethereal-plane

What would happen if a wizard summons a familiar (using *find familiar*) in the Border Ethereal, and then the wizard returns to the Material Plane (interrupting or ending the magical effects of *etherealness*)?

Would the familiar disappear due to the distance from the caster, since they are now on different planes?
Or
Does the Ethereal Plane overlap with the Material Plane (Border Ethereal) such  that distances are preserved and the familiar remains in the Border Ethereal while the caster is in the Material Plane?

> **The Ethereal Plane**
>   Its shores, called the Border Ethereal, overlap the Material Plane and the Inner Planes, so that every location on those planes has a corresponding location on the Ethereal Plane. (PHB, p. 301)

Does this make possible the ability of having one's familiar become an ethereal traveler?

Comment: You're posting ***a lot*** of questions about how individual spells interact with the Ethereal plane. The impression given is that you're trying to solve a problem piece-by-piece by yourself, instead of just telling us your problem and letting *us* solve it. The latter is what the site needs for questions to work. What problem are all these questions trying to solve? Do you have a main question about how the Ethereal works?

Comment: About the number of question, there is not a "big problem" that connected all my questions, I'm trying to understand better what are the proprieties of the ethereal plane. With this question in particular if it would be possible take on account the possibility of have a ethereal traveler familiar. Ethereal plane, like simulacrum or magic jar, is one of the most complex features that should deserve these number of questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The familiar, once summoned, does not have any limitations on where it can go, or what its distance from its owner can be.  There's a distance limit for using its senses, and the DM would have to make a ruling on that aspect -- is the ethereal plane within 100 linear feet of the material plane?

But there's no reason you couldn't summon a familiar on the ethereal plane, and leave.  Or summon it normally on the material plane, and send it to the ethereal plane by one of several methods.  Or summon it in either place, temporarily dismiss it into its pocket dimension, change the plane you're on, and have it reappear wherever you are.