# Question about cosmology in 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, planes, cosmology

I have a question about cosmology.

I googled for a long time, but did not find the answer to this question anywhere. We have a prime material plane, inside of which crystal spheres(also called worlds) float in the streams of phlogiston. I understand that feywild and shadowfell each of these worlds will have its own. But what about the outer and inner plans? Let's even take elementary plans. Can the same elemental be summoned from Eberron, for example, and from Toril? Or each world has its own outer / inner plans.

As far as I know, only the world of Athas(dark sun) has an different arrangement of the inner planes due to its peculiarities, but does this mean that in all other worlds the pool of creatures from the outer / inner planes is the same ?
Do beings from these planes know about the existence of other worlds?

Comment: I'm not positive it matters, but are you interested in older lore or just in what 5e says about this?

Comment: @NautArch I'm interested in both. But as far as I know 5e is not very different in this regard from older editions, I wrote this just in case

Comment: Very related: [Is it possible to move between the worlds of the Material Plane by travelling through the Border Ethereal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/184453)

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, that question seems to be asking the same thing.